# using keytool and jarsigner to sign my app

Tags: android, keytool, commonsware, jarsigner

I'm using both my commonsware book and the android docs that describe how to sign my app.  But there is something I don't understand...

I have generated my KeyStore file with no problem.

Now the commonsware book says to "Build a Release Version which should give you an unsigned.apk file in your project's bin/directory"  but it doesn't tell how to do that.  I can't see how to do it in Eclipse. There appears to be no Build -> Release menu item. Tried googling around and couldn't find anything.

The Android docs say "2. Compile the application in release mode" and then tell you to "Export unsigned application package" and then store it away somewhare.  I did that and now I have two apk files.  one in my bin directory and the one I exported.  Now it says to use jarsigner and zipaligner and I'm left to assume (it doesn't say) I'm doing this to the exported apk I have stored away (not the one in my bin directory).  Then do I just copy back this stored away apk over the one in my bin directory??  Won't it be wiped out the next time I compile?

This is way harder and a lot less fun that writing the app was.

Can someone set me straight?
Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't see how to do it in Eclipse.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile

> Then do I just copy back this stored away apk over the one in my bin directory?

No. You distribute it. Upload it to the Play Store. Or ship it on your Web site. Or copy it to ten million USB thumb drives and hand-deliver them to potential users. Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.  I suppose I can just copy (somehow) this new production apk to my phone for further testing and it will coexist with the debug version?

Comment: @user1058647 no, it cannot co-exist with the debug version, because they both have the same package name.

Comment: Commonsware: my app uses google api and mapview.  I read that once I use the release keys the map will only show if distributed via Google Play??  Is that correct??

Comment: @user1058647: AFAIK, neither Maps V1 nor Maps V2 require distribution via Google Play. The *device* will need to have some stuff on it (e.g., Google Play Services Framework for Maps V2), but that is not your responsibility.